# pymssql problem - INSERT does not work with parameters

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, pymssql

I'm using pymssql to do database programming with Python on Linux.

I'm having problems with passing parameters to queries. This problem only seems to exist with INSERT queries.

This works:

```
query = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col3=%s"
cur.execute(query, (value,))
```

But this doesn't:

```
query = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cur.execute(query, (value1, value2,))
```

Any idea why the INSERT query won't work?

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 46, in ?
    cur.execute(query, (value1, value2,))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pymssql.py", line 126, in execute
    self.executemany(operation, (params,))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pymssql.py", line 152, in executemany
    raise DatabaseError, "internal error: %s" % self.__source.errmsg()
pymssql.DatabaseError: internal error: None
```

Comment: The same example works for me with MySQL-python 1.2.3 which ships with Fedora 13.

Comment: It does indeed work in MySQL, but I'm using MSSQL. :(

Comment: What are the actual values of the variables value1 and value2?

Comment: didn't spot that, thought it was mysql. I'd take it up with the author of pymssql if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out one of the values I was trying to insert was of type unicode. When I converted it to string, using `str(value1)`, the query worked.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
cur.execute(query % (value1, value2))
```

Comment: No, that is not how dbi-api is supposed to be used and will lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities.